# Can Notepad++ convert multiple opened files to ANSI (encoding)?

Tags: notepad++, encoding

I have 50 text files which need to be converted from utf-8 bom to ANSI. In Notepad++ We can do it with single file, but I want all opened files to be converted to ANSI in one short way. Is there any option there?

Comment: It seems that u need a way in command line to do it. Have you looked for a powershell solution?

Comment: i did not try., im not a power user or script writer. just looking for a tool that could do this job. any other way?. if it can be done in command line please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that your utf8bom files are in `c:\temp\utf8\`

I am saving the ansi files to `c:\temp\ansi\`

At command line,

```
> powershell
PS> get-item c:\temp\utf8\*.* | foreach-object {get-content $_ | out-file ("c:\temp\ansi\" + $_.Name) -encoding default}
PS> exit
>
```

What it does is that for each file in `c:\temp\utf8`, get its content and output to a file with the same filename in `c:\temp\ansi` with the Windows system default encoding, which is equivalent to ANSI you meant.

`get-content` command here can read the text without you specifying utf8 with or without bom.